# Display image in PHP given image content

Tags: php, image, screen-grab

I'm using the GrabzIt PHP library and it returns screenshots of webpages.

The library returns the image content to be saved as a file, e.g:

```
file_put_contents('images/screenshot.png', $grabzitImageContents);
```

I want to display this image in the page without saving the image (uses server space). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just send the header and then echo the data:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $grabzitImageContents;
```

Try it.

Comment: This won't work if the OP's intention is to display it directly within an HTML page.

Comment: Haha that's the first thing I tried. I think there's something wrong with the GrabzIt code because neither answer is working. Lemme check...

Comment: @apparatix This should work, but your script should only echo out this and nothing else. The source of the image in the html would be the image generating script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
$encoded = base64_encode($grabzitImageContents);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $encoded . '" />';
```